# combine result of 2 data frame generated in for loop for 2 input values

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

combine result of 2 data frame generated in for loop for 2 input values
here is the data frame :

1st DF for first value in for loop:

```
+--------+-------------------------------+---+
|order_id|Diff                           |id |
+--------+-------------------------------+---+
|12      |order_status                   |1  |
|1       |order_customer_id order_status |1  |
|68885   |New row in DataFrame 2         |1  |
|68886   |New row in DataFrame 2         |1  |
|2       |order_customer_id              |1  |
+--------+-------------------------------+---+
```

2nd DF for first value in for loop:

```
+--------+-------------------------------+---+
|order_id|Diff                           |id |
+--------+-------------------------------+---+
|12      |order_status                   |2  |
|1       |order_customer_id order_status |2  |
|68885   |New row in DataFrame 2         |2  |
|68886   |New row in DataFrame 2         |2  |
|2       |order_customer_id              |2  |
+--------+-------------------------------+---+
```

want to combine both of the above at the end  - also it can be more than 2  so want final result as combined DF. can anyone have any logic?

Comment: not sure if I got you right - but if I did you need to union the dataframes df1.union(df2)

Comment: It's not clear what is your question from title. 
Question is unclear

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following loop that generates a sequence of DataFrames:

```
import spark.implicits._
val dfs: Seq[DataFrame] = List(List((1,1)), List((2,2)), List((3,3))).map(l => l.toDF("a","b"))
```

You can use the `union` function in order to combine them:

```
val combinedDf = dfs.reduce(_ union _)
combinedDf.show()

+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  3|  3|
+---+---+
```